# Android: What's the default value of android:dividerHeight for a listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, divider

Simple question: What is the default value of `android:dividerHeight` for a normal listview? I bet you can probably look it up somewhere, but I wouldn't know where.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The intrinsic height of the image which is 3px. You can find the android source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the other answers are just partly right.
The ListView_dividerHeight is stylable but Android itself doesn't set a default value (at least not the stock Android). If the app itself doesn't set the value like this e.g.:

```
<item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
```

then @android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque will be used which exists in four different "flavors" (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi).

So the "real" answer is: there's no way to tell. It depends on:

- Screen density
- Android version
- Customization by the manufacturer
- App theming
- possibly other factors

To find these answers yourself check out your Android SDK folder: platforms\android-17\data\res\values\attrs.xml / styles.xml / themes.xml (android-17 might be different for your installation) and read the documentation about themes & styles: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

//you can see in your Android SDK folder
divider is just an 9-patch image

```
android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-xx\data\res\values\styles.xml



<style name="Widget.ListView" parent="Widget.AbsListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">?android:attr/colorBackgroundCacheHint</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark_opaque</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.ListView.White" parent="Widget.AbsListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">?android:attr/colorBackgroundCacheHint</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

i bet that it depends on android version/style being used/phone manufacturer changes.

quick look at the android sources:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.ListView, defStyle, 0);

// Use the height specified, zero being the default
final int dividerHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.ListView_dividerHeight, 0);
if (dividerHeight != 0) {
    setDividerHeight(dividerHeight);
}
```